# Automorphism of a Cayley graph

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, cayley-graphs

When considering the Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ with respect to the generating set $S=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$, as shown in Figure (1) below, can I regard the graph in Figure (2) as one of its automorphisms?

[image: Figure (1)]

[image: Figure (2)]

[image: Figure (3)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to ask if your second graph represents the Cayley graph of your group with respect to the generating set $\{(0,1),(1,1)\}$ corresponding to the automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ given by

$$(0,1)\mapsto (0,1) \quad(1,0)\mapsto (1,1)$$

then yes it does.

Comment: Thanks @SantanaAfton but it is not very clear to me. Does that mean that automorphisms of the Cayley graph are generated by different generating sets?

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika Are you asking about automorphisms of the **group** or automorphisms of the **graph**?

Comment: Automorphisms of the graph

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika If you’re asking about automorphisms of the graph then it’s unclear to me how your second picture should represent an automorphism, unless you draw the same graph in Figure 1 but relabel the vertices (as this gives the information as to what vertices are sent to what vertices under the automorphism).

Comment: Then @SantanaAfton instead of vertex $(1,1)$, vertex $(1,0)$ and instead of $(2,2)$, vertex $(2,0)$ ... Should be present in Figure (2) right?

Comment: the new figure added to the edited question above, is an automorphism of the graph represented in Figure (1)? Is it correct? :)

Comment: And is it correct if I say that the permutation (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) represents Figure (1) and then, (1 2 3 6 4 5 8 9 7) represents Figure (3)?

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika Unfortunately I don’t think I understand. An automorphism of a graph $(V,E)$ is just a function $V\to V$ that preserves adjacency. If you want to draw a picture that represents the automorphism of a graph, it should somehow be clear which vertices are getting sent where. Both Figure 2 and Figure 3 tell me little about how they relate to Figure 1 because you’ve changed how you’re drawing the graph.

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika As to your permutations, I’m not sure where you’re getting them. You should be explicit and clear about what your numbers “1”, “2”, and so on and representing.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much @SantanaAfton . I will try again to draw a proper automorphism of the graph